# Using ngFor to create different element types

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am iterating through an array of strings (called words), and want to create span elements for each word, and br elements for end of line characters (\n) using Angular/Typescript. I've got the ngFor directive working:

```
<div id = documentContents *ngIf="showDocument">
    <span *ngFor="let word of words" >
        {{word}}
    </span>
</div>
```

It currently creates spans from everything, even the br elements in the array. Note: while parsing the document, I create br elements out of the end of line characters. Not married to this solution, just seemed like a good idea. Logically I want to do something like:

```
if(word != "<br/>") {
    <span> {{word}} </span>
}
else {
    create a <br/> element
}
```

Where all the spans and br elements get appended to the containing div and the original source format is maintained (As much as possible)

But am unsure how to implement the ngIf portion. I've experimented with putting the ngFor directive on the containing div element (docContents) but then it generates div elements vice spans (to be expected). I've written something similar using javascript and was just a simple matter of document.append(span or br element). It's probably a simple thing but it escapes me. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

Place your `*ngFor` on an `<ng-container>`, it won't add an extra element to the DOM at runtime.

And put an inner `*ngIf` with a template reference to an `<ng-template>` to handle the else part:

```
<div id = documentContents *ngIf="showDocument">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let word of words" >
        <span *ngIf="word !== '\n'; else br">{{ word }}</span>
        <ng-template #br><br /></ng-template>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

[Here is an article](https://alligator.io/angular/ng-container-element/) on `<ng-container>` if you want more information.

Comment: Works great, but question. Does the "else br" reference the "ng-template #br"? Guess I've not gotten that far in the books! Also will google ng-container as well.

Comment: Yes exactly, br references the #br reference placed on the <ng-template>, that way, you don't have to repeat the condition, just specifiy an else part. This is quite handy when the condition is long, which in your case is not really a problem

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative to @jo_va's answer, which IMO is a slightly easier to read:

```
<div id="documentContents" *ngIf="showDocument">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let word of words">
    <span *ngIf="word !== '\n'">{{word}}</span>
    <br *ngIf="word === '\n'">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

This simply displays a span if the word is anything but a newline, and a `<br>` otherwise.

The only downside is repeating the condition, which can be fixed by adding a simple `isNewline()` method on the component and using `!isNewLine()` / `isNewLine()` instead.

**Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prkeyy**

Comment: Why re-evalute the logic statement just for cleaner syntax ? Not a very performant solution for anything more complex than string comparison.

Comment: @Zze It's most of the time a bad idea to have complex conditions in your template. If you have complex conditions, that means you should probably have a component property instead, and use the condition on it.

Comment: I don't see any complexity here though, it's a simple `if else` ?

Comment: Agreed it may not be as performant, but it was easier for me to understand the syntax. I'm a crawl walk run kinda guy. Jeto's solution helped me understand what's going on, while jo_va's is cleaner. Thanks to both of you. I've read the posted article on containers, and viewed Jato's running code. Y'all rock.

Comment: @Zze You did mention "anything more complex than string comparison". My point is that, as you mentioned, it's a very simple condition so there is no performance issue whatsoever. Having non-basic conditions on your template should almost never happen so repeating them is pretty much a non-issue.